# VLookup throws errors for some values but not others

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

VLookup is throwing an error when I search for some string values and not others:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the VLookup property of the Worksheet Function class

Apparently this error indicates that there was no value found BUT to my human eye the values match!

Is this the result of a hidden character or a space or something I can't see?

How do I go about ensuring that values on one page are actually the same as values on another?

Also, I thought that maybe I'm not searching where I think I'm searching which would explain why I can't find some of the values. As a test I changed the return value in the column and the change came back correctly. Then I change the lookup value which should have thrown an error but it didn't. It returned a different value instead. I searched for "United States" which isn't there and instead it returned the value for "United Kingdom" instead.

Comment: Try your vlookup without the `worksheetFunction` Just do `Application.Vlookup...`

Comment: Are the values you're looking for numbers or text? Are they formatted as numbers or text?

Comment: In your data set use the clean function to and trim function `=Trim(Clean(A1))` this will should get rid of any unwanted characters.

Comment: @scott - what is the difference between using the worksheetFunction and Application forms? Also, when I tried just taking out the worksheetFunction portion of the code I receive a type mismatch.

Comment: @Enigmativity I checked and they are all general format values in both sets of data (the search terms and in the range to be searched).

Comment: See [This](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/584913-application-vs-application-worksheetfunction.html). One of the answers gives a great answer to the difference.  As to the type mismatch without the code it is hard to figure out.

Comment: @ScottCraner type mismatch may occur with any strongly-typed variable container because the `Application.Vlookup` can return an `Error` type, so  if you're assigning the result of `Application.VLookup`, need to assign it to a variant type, and then test for error -- IOW you can't assign an Error value to a `Long` data type, etc.

Comment: @DavidZemens You are correct and it is good to have as an explanation for future reference. I was aware of that I wanted to see the code before assuming that was the issue. :) But it appears as of the last edit that the OP may have figured out the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Ok, palm to face moment.  The data set that I was searching through is fairly large so somehow when I set the named range it was only set on a sub-set of the data! Not sure how that happended...

This still doesn't explain the inconsistent results for "United Statess" returning "United Kingdom" instead which just made debugging that much harder.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is the full formula you're using? It's perfectly expected in some circumstances that VLOOKUP will return an "approximate" match unless you use the Exact Match parameter, OR the data is alpha-sorted.

Comment: @DavidZemens Yes, I believe that the I had the range_lookup value set to true which I didn't realise returned approximate matches.  *Sigh* Live and learn.

Comment: I got burned by that back in 2008, too. Mine went out to about a dozen clients before we caught the error!  Cheers.